# Laravel query buillder limit only the rows from a table even if in a join those rows have to appear more than once

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have 2 tables:

```
Foo
| id | car  |
_____________
| 1  |  A   |
| 2  |  B   |
| 3  |  C   |

Bar 
| car_id | color |
__________________
|   1    | red   |
|   1    | green |
|   1    | blue  | 
|   2    | pink  |
|   2    | red   |
|   3    | blue  |
```

I want to limit my join to 2 rows from **Foo** table(car A and B). For that i tried using this query:

```
$cars = \DB::table('Foo')->join('Bar', 'Bar.car_id', '=', 'Foo.id')
        ->select('Foo.car', 'Bar.color')
        ->take(2)
        ->get();
```

The problem with this query is that i'm getting only the first two results for car A since it appears twice in **Bar** table:

```
Result
[1] A, red
[2] A, green
```

But i want to get something like this:

```
Result
[1] A, red
[2] A, green
[3] A, blue
[4] B, pink
[5] B, red
```

How can i do that by using the query builder from laravel? (not Eloquent)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```php
$cars = \DB::table('Foo')->take(2)->join('Bar', 'Bar.car_id', '=', 'Foo.id')
        ->select('Foo.car', 'Bar.color')
        ->get();
```

doesn't work?